# Proper way to delete-if-exists?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a use case where I need to delete a document that may or may not exist. I delete like this

```
db.collection('cities').doc('DC').delete();
```

It works fine, but when the document doesn't exist, I get an error in the log, which I'd rather not see. I could read the document first to ensure it exists, but that seems wasteful. What's the proper delete-if-exists approach?

EDIT I'm performing this operation using Cloud Functions (JS)

Comment: Please provide which language or framework your using ?

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collection('cities').doc('DC').get().then(
     doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          db.collection('cities').doc('DC').delete().then(() => {
             console.log("Doc deleted!")
          })
        }
     }
 );
```

Comment: So we do need to read the doc to confirm it exists before deleting?

Comment: In your example, `db.collection('cities').doc('DC')` that is a document reference. Here is some info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference, And what you have should work as expected. Realize it returns a promise which you'll need to wait to be resolved before knowing if it was deleted. I am pretty sure it is find running a `delete()` on a non-existent document reference

Answer (score 0):

You can also use async/await and reuse the same doc for both actions

```js
const doc = db.collection('cities').doc('DC')
const snapshot = await doc.get()
if (snapshot.exists) await doc.delete()
```